# How to parse curl response with no html <head> <body>?

Tags: php, curl, html-parsing

So the response I got from curl is a part of the `<body>`.

It starts with tag `<input >` not with the `<html><head><body>`.

How do I parse it? I've tried with simple_html_dom with no result , should I use regex instead?

Answer (score 1):

Try using the [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) object, the `loadHTML` method should accept html fragments and do the parsing for you.

```
$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->loadHtml($fragment);
$html = $doc->saveHTML();
```

Watch out for the potential warnings generated by parsing malformed html.

Comment: In my quick sanity test, throwing in a single `'<input>'` and then calling `saveHTML` produced a `<html><body><input></body></html>` under php 5.4.6

Comment: You are totally right, I once needed to wrap, but I can not reproduce. Deleted my answer as well, yours is very fine!